# Extract only text content from a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to extract all the text content from a web page. I have used 'document.body.textContent'.
But I get the javascript content as well.How do I ensure that I get only the readable text content?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.body.textContent
  alert(str);
}
```

```html
<html>
<title>Test Page for Text extraction</title>

<head>I hope this works</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Test on this content to change the 5th word to a link
    <p>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
</hmtl>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just remove the tags you dont want read before doing `body.textContent`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var bodyScripts = document.querySelectorAll("body script");
  for(var i=0; i<bodyScripts.length; i++){
      bodyScripts[i].remove();
  }
  var str = document.body.textContent;
  document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>'+str+'</pre>';
}
```

```html
<html>
<title>Test Page for Text extraction</title>

<head>I hope this works</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Test on this content to change the 5th word to a link
    <p>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
</hmtl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `document.body.innerText`.

[This MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext) describes the differences between `textContent` and `innerText`:

> Don't get confused by the differences between `Node.textContent` and
> `HTMLElement.innerText`. Although the names seem similar, there are
> important differences:
>
> - `textContent` gets the content of all elements, including `<script>` and
>   `<style>` elements. In contrast, `innerText` only shows "human-readable"
>   elements.
> - `textContent` returns every element in the node. In contrast,
>   `innerText` is aware of styling and won't return the text of "hidden"
>   elements.